# BSound: Conditionally Extract href text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to use a regular expression to conditionally grab "hrefs"? For exampe, below I only want the text (TUBB1 and TUBB2) of only two hrefs:

```
href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:*"
```

and just the text of the href target

```
href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04690" target="_blank">P04690</a>
```

My final goal is to have a list such as **[("TUBB1,"TUBB2"),P04960]**

Below is the HTML block I have gotten to with the text I want to extract.

```
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.ncbi_scientific_name:Chlamydomonas reinhardtii">Chlamydomonas reinhardtii</a>
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:TUBB1">TUBB1</a>
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:TUBB2">TUBB2</a>
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers.reference_sequence_identifiers.database_accession:P04690 AND rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers.reference_sequence_identifiers.database_name:UniProt">P04690</a>
<a href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04690" target="_blank">P04690</a>
<a href="/pdb/protein/P04690" target="_blank">P04690</a>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, do you want to select all elements where `href=` begins with `"/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:"` and one element where `href=` begins with `"http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"` ?

Comment: Exactly! I think I managed to just string search "hrefs". Curious if there is a regex was to grab them. Maybe with a more expensive task the string searching/in will break or take wicked long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is one possible solution to select the required elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.ncbi_scientific_name:Chlamydomonas reinhardtii">Chlamydomonas reinhardtii</a>
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:TUBB1">TUBB1</a>
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:TUBB2">TUBB2</a>
<a class="querySearchLink" href="/search?q=rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers.reference_sequence_identifiers.database_accession:P04690 AND rcsb_polymer_entity_container_identifiers.reference_sequence_identifiers.database_name:UniProt">P04690</a>
<a href="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P04690" target="_blank">P04690</a>
<a href="/pdb/protein/P04690" target="_blank">P04690</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# select all text from elements where href begins with "/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:"
part_1 = tuple(s.text for s in soup.select('[href^="/search?q=rcsb_entity_source_organism.rcsb_gene_name.value:"]'))

# select text from first element where href begins with "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"
part_2 = soup.select_one('[href^="http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/"]').text

# combine parts and print them:
print([part_1, part_2])
```

Prints:

```
[('TUBB1', 'TUBB2'), 'P04690']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its sexy, but I guess this will do.

```
z=i.find_all('a')

for j in z:
    if "_gene_name" in j['href']:
        print(j.text)
    if "/pdb/protein" in j['href']:
        print(j.text)
```

Output:

```
TUBB1
TUBB2
P04690
```